# WPF DataGrid styling

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles, resourcedictionary

I'm trying to style the WPF datagrid. I'm using the Whistler Blue theme (full source at http://pastebin.com/5nXpTw4G), but although the column headers are styled, the selected row is not, it's just awful looking dark blue. I noticed from inspecting the visual tree with snoop that the controls in the templates for each cell/row aren't rendered.

**EDIT:** The WhistlerBlue theme source is available at http://wpfthemes.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/63656#382026

Comment: Your link is not available, so your question it's impossible to understand!

Answer (score 0):

Try the [WPF DataGrid Themes from Silverlight](http://datagridthemesfromsl.codeplex.com/) CodePlex project.